# how to call a .cs file from main form in csharp

Tags: c#, .net

I want to call a .cs file from my form1.cs file.

I have written a minimize to system tray code in sys_tray.cs file and so when I clicked to minimize option on form1.cs a new form resize function will be called and in that function I want to call the sys_tray.cs file. How do I do this?

Comment: @user661921: Please elaborate a bit on what you need exactly. If you expect specific, high-quality answers, you should spend some time making clear what you're trying to do, where you are stuck, and what you've tried thus far.

Comment: Reading a few tutorials, intros, books on C# should answer your question.  You don't "call" .cs files.  I think you need to develop a basic understanding of programming and .NET first.

Comment: in addition to developing a basic understanding of programming, you should also develop a basic understanding of how to ask questions with detail

Answer (score 1):

On the minimize event in the form create an object of the sys_tray class and call the function you want to use. 
Do provide more specific information for people to suggest answers with more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

When you wrote sys_tray.cs, I believe you wrote a class and have a function in that class. Am I right?

For discussion purpose, let's assume it's class SysTray and function Mini.

Now, for that function is it declared static? If yes, you can simply call that function with the code `SysTray.Mini();`

If the function is not static, consider whether it should be made static. Typically it should be static if the function does not access any member variables.

If it isn't going to be static, then you will need to create an instance of the class before calling the function:

```
SysTray tray = new SysTray();
tray.Mini();
```

Please make sure the namespace in your Form1.cs and your sys_tray.cs is the same. If they are not the same, you might want to use the full namespace when specifying `SysTray`. eg: `MyOtherNameSpace.SysTray`

Of course all of the above won't work if sys_tray.cs is not compiled together with Form1.cs. It depends on what you're using to edit your code. Typically, if you're using Visual Studio / Visual C#, you will have to add sys_tray.cs to your project. You may have created sys_tray.cs via the Add new Item to project context menu. In this case, there is nothing else you need to do. Simply compile and run the project.

If you create sys_tray.cs via the File > New menu. You will have to right click your project and add existing file. Select sys_tray.cs.

If you are using the basic compiler only, csc. Then just append sys_tray.cs right after Form1.cs when you call csc.